# Can't auto-generate C# object from fetched json

Tags: c#, json, object, dynamically-generated

I've already looked into many other posts and the solution is always the same but it doesn't work for me so here I go.

I have the following `HttpClient` that fetches a JSON string and stores it in a variable.

**JSON**

```
{"visiteur":{"id":"a17","nom":"Andre","prenom":"David","login":"dandre","mdp":"12e0b9be32932a8028b0ef0432a0a0a99421f745","adresse":"1 rue Petit","cp":"46200","ville":"Lalbenque","dateEmbauche":"1998-11-23","idTypeActeur":"2","oldMdp":"oppg5","mail":"david.andre@gsb.com","questionSecrete":"GSB","version":"0"}}
```

**Client**

```
// url de récupération du json de l'acteur
            string urlActeur = "http://10.0.0.5/ppe3JoJuAd/gsbAppliFraisV2/webservices/w_visiteur.php" + "?" + "login=" + Login + "&" + "pass=" + Pass;

            //instanciation du client http qui envoi un header json
            HttpClient clientActeur = new HttpClient();
            clientActeur.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            clientActeur.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //réponse à la requête Http
            var response = await clientActeur.GetAsync(urlActeur);
            var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var acteurJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActeurJson>(json);
```

Here are the contents of the JSON variable:

```
{"visiteur":{"id":"a17","nom":"Andre","prenom":"David","login":"dandre","mdp":"12e0b9be32932a8028b0ef0432a0a0a99421f745","adresse":"1 rue Petit","cp":"46200","ville":"Lalbenque","dateEmbauche":"1998-11-23","idTypeActeur":"2","oldMdp":"oppg5","mail":"david.andre@gsb.com","questionSecrete":"GSB","version":"0"}}
```

So it *does* fetch the JSON, and stores it in the variable, but looking at my `acteurJson` variable I get a `null` object.

**classes** validated with json2csharp:

```
public class Acteur
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("nom")]
        public string nom { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("prenom")]
        public string prenom { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("login")]
        public string login { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("mdp")]
        public string mdp { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("adresse")]
        public string adresse { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("cp")]
        public string cp { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ville")]
        public string ville { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("dateEmbauche")]
        public string dateEmbauche { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("idTypeActeur")]
        public string idTypeActeur { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("oldMdp")]
        public string oldMdp { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("mail")]
        public string mail { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("questionSecrete")]
        public string questionSecrete { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("version")]
        public string version { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActeurJson
    {
        public Acteur Acteur { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to get the JSON from the JSON variable to generate an `Acteur` object automatically. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON data is `{"visiteur":{...} }`. For `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActeurJson>` to work, the name of the C# property needs to match the name of the property in the JSON object:

```
public class ActeurJson
{
    public Acteur Visiteur { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `JsonPropertyAttribute` to override the name of the C# property:

```
public class ActeurJson
{
    [JsonProperty("visiteur")]
    public Acteur Acteur { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have got Acteur and ActeurJson classes, whereas the string representation is matching with that of Acteur. If you change the Deserialization line to

```
var acteurJson = new ActeurJson() { Acteur = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Acteur>(json)};
```

should solve your problem.